# Junit import using * wildcard

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I've noticed that when importing JUnit, the * wildcard doesn't always work.
e.g. for the annotation @Test you must import org.junit.Test since org.junit.* doesn't recognize the annotation.

Is there a reason for this, is it something that needs setting? or just a quirk in the way somethings like JUnit are.

FYI, I am using: Junit 4.6, Intelli-J 8.1.3.

Comment: Attach a screenshot, otherwise people here won't believe you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above:

> I've copy-pasted it and got "annontation type expected".

it sounds to me like it could be a name collision. Are you importing a class or interface named Test from somewhere else? Is there a class named Test in the same package as the one where you're having the problem? It could be that Java is seeing one of these instead of the annotation.

Comment: "Test" is a *very* generic name, and I suspect a name collision as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading something at http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t369296-p2-disadvantage-of-using-wildcards-in-import-statement.html that suggests that there's an "optimize imports" setting in IntelliJ that might relate to this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason I know of why importing org.junit.* wouldn't give you access to org.junit.Test.  In fact, I just tried it in Eclipse, and it works there.  Perhaps it's a problem with your IDEA workspace?

Comment: Would suggest that there's a setting for it or a larger issue that is my problem. I find it hard to believe that Intelli-J is simply broken in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do it, but using `import org.junit.*;` works fine here, the following test turns on a green light:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

import org.junit.*;

public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Tested with Java 6u16 on the command line, under Eclipse 3.5, under IntelliJ IDEA 9.0 BETA CE. Works everywhere as expected.

[alt text http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7906/screenshotmavenpowermoc.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7906/screenshotmavenpowermoc.png)

Comment: In which IDEA does it work for you? I've copy-pasted it and got "annontation type expected".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today in Eclipse. I made a static import to org.junit.Assert.assertEquals, but a static import of org.junit.Assert.assertThat fails!  And they are in the same class!

I'll bet it's an Eclipse bug.  I'm using junit 4.4 and eclipse 3.5

Comment: I use Intelli-J (as noted in the tags of this question), so it's not just Eclipse.